# How to completely clean Spacemacs from the not longer required mode?

Tags: spacemacs

Once I enable a local major-mode.  After some time I decided to remove it.  So I deleted it from disk as well as from configuration (<kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>).   But it is still available in my Spacemacs.  At least I see all its functions in <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>.

How I can remove it completely ? Is there sort of "compiled cache"?

I'm not even sure that this is just the eval history.  Because I can call these functions/vars and see the result of their work.  As if i didn't remove the major mode at all.  Of course, I restarted my Spacemacs many times (<kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Use commands like `M-x locate-library` or `M-x find-library` to find the location of your library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that all this time I had Emacs running in daemon mode, and I was using (and restarting) the client.

Comment: Please accept your own answer as soon as possible.